# Position tcolorbox in an absolute manner

Tags: positioning, tcolorbox

I'd like to position a `tcolorbox` in an absolute manner, like in tikz option `remember picture, overlay`, with something like "please put the center of the box at the center of the page". What is the easiest way to achieve that ?

Thank you !

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=4cm]%%
  Hi everyone
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can wrap it into a tikz node.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\begin{document}
\tikz[overlay, remember picture] \node at (current page.center) {
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=4cm]%%
  Hi everyone
\end{tcolorbox}
};
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, thank you very much ! I though that it was not possible to include a tikz picture inside a tikz node, so it means that tcolorbox is not a tikz picture ?

Comment: @tobiasBora I do not think so. I thought it uses low-level pgf, but I might be wrong. What I know is that the tikzpicture around works.