# wrong Notepad when use \node and \tikz

Tags: tcolorbox

i want to resize and move Notepad from link: [poster-layout: background and boxes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263161/poster-layout-background-and-boxes)
and link
[Change width, height of Notepad](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/481433/change-width-height-of-notepad/481437?noredirect=1#comment1216801_481437)

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{mybrown}{RGB}{33,34,28}
\definecolor{myyellow}{RGB}{242,226,149}
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{176,232,145}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{61,139,189}
\definecolor{myorange}{RGB}{245,156,74}
\definecolor{mypurple}{RGB}{230,111,148}
\definecolor{myred}{RGB}{215,80,50}

\newtcolorbox{NotePad}[2][]{%
  enhanced,
  frame code=empty,
  boxsep=0.5cm,
  top=0.6cm,
  interior code={
  \fill[#2,drop shadow]
    (interior.south west) {[rounded corners=1.5cm]--
    (interior.south east)} --
    (interior.north east) --
    (interior.north west) --
    cycle;
  \fill[#2!80!black] 
    ([shift={(-0.9cm,0.5ex)}]interior.south east) to[out=30,in=-70]
    ([shift={(-0.55cm,0.7cm)}]interior.south east) to[out=-10,in=220]
    ([shift={(-0.7ex,0.9cm)}]interior.south east) to[out=250,in=30]
    cycle;  
  \fill[mybrown]
    ([yshift=-10pt]interior.north) circle [radius=0.23cm];
  \fill[mybrown!40]
    ([yshift=-10pt]interior.north) circle [radius=0.175cm];
  \node[
    cylinder,
    cylinder uses custom fill, 
    cylinder end fill=mybrown!60,
    cylinder body fill=mybrown,
    rotate=115,
    minimum width=9pt,
    minimum height=16pt
  ] 
  at ([shift={(-0.2pt,-9.8pt)}]interior.north) {};
  },
  #1
}



\begin{document}


%\column{.5\textwidth}
\tikz[overlay, remember picture] 
\node[anchor=south east,xshift=5.5cm, yshift=-3cm]
{
\begin{NotePad}[width=10cm,height =4cm]{myyellow}
Some test text for this block
\end{NotePad}
}
\tikz[overlay, remember picture] 
\node[anchor=south east,xshift=7.5cm, yshift=-10cm]
{
\begin{NotePad}[width=5cm,height=10cm]{myblue}
 test text 
\end{NotePad}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please see attachment, this button of Notepad display wrong.
Thanks

Comment: Your approach nests `tikzpicture`s, which should be avoided, and leads to these effects. It is quite possible that, if you either use a `\savebox`  for the cylinder or draw it with more basic methods, the problem will disappear, but as long as you nest `tikzpicture`s you will never have full control.

Comment: To add to @marmot's comment: `tcolorbox` uses `tikz` so by using `tcolorbox` inside a `tikz` environment you're nesting `tikz` inside `tikz.`

Comment: @marmot  JPi thank for comment. I see answer in link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398012/position-tcolorbox-in-an-absolute-manner. Can you correct above code? Thanks

Comment: I do not necessarily agree with [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398012/position-tcolorbox-in-an-absolute-manner). If you put a `tcolorbox` in a node it is always a gamble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tcbposter` is an environment offered by `tcolorbox` which allows easy ways for placing and dimensioning `posterboxes`. If you could use `tcbposter` you will avoid problems related with nesting `tikzpictures`.

Following code shows a little example. I've converted `NotePad` boxes to a `tcbset` style and used this style to configure `posterboxes`. As it's seen, `posterbox` dimensions can be automatically determined by poster grid or relative to other boxes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{mybrown}{RGB}{33,34,28}
\definecolor{myyellow}{RGB}{242,226,149}
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{176,232,145}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{61,139,189}
\definecolor{myorange}{RGB}{245,156,74}
\definecolor{mypurple}{RGB}{230,111,148}
\definecolor{myred}{RGB}{215,80,50}

\tcbset{
NotePad/.style={%
  enhanced,
  frame code=empty,
  boxsep=0.5cm,
  top=0.6cm,
  interior code={
  \fill[#1,drop shadow]
    (interior.south west) {[rounded corners=1.5cm]--
    (interior.south east)} --
    (interior.north east) --
    (interior.north west) --
    cycle;
  \fill[#1!80!black] 
    ([shift={(-0.9cm,0.5ex)}]interior.south east) to[out=30,in=-70]
    ([shift={(-0.55cm,0.7cm)}]interior.south east) to[out=-10,in=220]
    ([shift={(-0.7ex,0.9cm)}]interior.south east) to[out=250,in=30]
    cycle;  
  \fill[mybrown]
    ([yshift=-10pt]interior.north) circle [radius=0.23cm];
  \fill[mybrown!40]
    ([yshift=-10pt]interior.north) circle [radius=0.175cm];
  \node[
    cylinder,
    cylinder uses custom fill, 
    cylinder end fill=mybrown!60,
    cylinder body fill=mybrown,
    rotate=115,
    minimum width=9pt,
    minimum height=16pt
  ] 
  at ([shift={(-0.2pt,-9.8pt)}]interior.north) {};
  },
}}



\begin{document}
\begin{tcbposter}[%
    poster={columns=3, rows=3},
    ]
    \posterbox[NotePad=myyellow]{name=A, column=1, span=2}{Some test text for this block}
    \posterbox[NotePad=myblue]{name=B, column=3, rowspan=3}{Some test text for this block}
    \posterbox[NotePad=myorange]{name=C, between=A and bottom, span=2}{Some test text for this block}
    \posterbox[NotePad=mypurple]{column=2, row=2, span=1.5, rowspan=1.5}{Some test text for this block}
    \posterbox[NotePad=mygreen]{at=C.west, xshift=1cm, yshift=-2cm}{Some test text for this block}

\end{tcbposter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One should not nest `tikzpicture`s, but this is what you are doing because `tcolorbox` is based on Ti*k*Z. As explained in [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47377/121799), what you always can do is to store the inner `tikzpicture` in a `\savebox`, and the use this `\savebox` in an node of the outer `tikzpicture`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{mybrown}{RGB}{33,34,28}
\definecolor{myyellow}{RGB}{242,226,149}
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{176,232,145}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{61,139,189}
\definecolor{myorange}{RGB}{245,156,74}
\definecolor{mypurple}{RGB}{230,111,148}
\definecolor{myred}{RGB}{215,80,50}

\newtcolorbox{NotePad}[2][]{%
  enhanced,
  frame code=empty,
  boxsep=0.5cm,
  top=0.6cm,
  interior code={
  \fill[#2,drop shadow]
    (interior.south west) {[rounded corners=1.5cm]--
    (interior.south east)} --
    (interior.north east) --
    (interior.north west) --
    cycle;
  \fill[#2!80!black] 
    ([shift={(-0.9cm,0.5ex)}]interior.south east) to[out=30,in=-70]
    ([shift={(-0.55cm,0.7cm)}]interior.south east) to[out=-10,in=220]
    ([shift={(-0.7ex,0.9cm)}]interior.south east) to[out=250,in=30]
    cycle;  
  \fill[mybrown]
    ([yshift=-10pt]interior.north) circle [radius=0.23cm];
  \fill[mybrown!40]
    ([yshift=-10pt]interior.north) circle [radius=0.175cm];
  \node[
    cylinder,
    cylinder uses custom fill, 
    cylinder end fill=mybrown!60,
    cylinder body fill=mybrown,
    rotate=115,
    minimum width=9pt,
    minimum height=16pt
  ] 
  at ([shift={(-0.2pt,-9.8pt)}]interior.north) {};
  },
  #1
}


\newsavebox{\NPA}
\newsavebox{\NPB}

\begin{document}
\begin{lrbox}{\NPA}%
\begin{NotePad}[width=10cm,height =4cm]{myyellow}
Some test text for this block
\end{NotePad}%
\end{lrbox}%
\begin{lrbox}{\NPB}%
\begin{NotePad}[width=5cm,height=10cm]{myblue}
 test text 
\end{NotePad}%
\end{lrbox}%

%\column{.5\textwidth}
\tikz[overlay, remember picture]%
{\node[anchor=south east,xshift=5.5cm, yshift=-3cm]
{
\usebox\NPA
};}
\tikz[overlay, remember picture]%
{\node[anchor=south east,xshift=7.5cm, yshift=-10cm]
{
\usebox\NPB
};}

\end{document}
```

[image]